# Connection of FTP and read xml file using php

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, ftp

I have connect FTP through PHP and try to read `.xml` file , but I am getting warning that file can't found.

```
$date =  date('d');

$path = dirname(__FILE__)."/data/".$date;

$ftp_server = "xyz.com";

$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");

$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, 'uname', 'pwd');

$file_list = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, ".");

$file_lists = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn,$file_list[2].'/'.date("Y/m/d"));

ftp_pasv($login, true);
ob_start();
ftp_get($ftp_conn,$path,$file_list[2].'/'.date("Y/m/d").'/'.$file_lists[0], FTP_ASCII);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
ftp_close($ftp_conn);        
var_dump($data);
```

How can I read `.xml` file?

Comment: try to `var_dump($file_lists)`

Comment: If i am use it than getting list of file , but i want to read each file and get all data

Comment: 1. you don't need output buffering here 2. do you see your file in `$file_lists` array?

Comment: Yes , I can see list of file , so i used that `$file_lists[0]`

Answer (score 0):

In fact [ftp_get()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php) is just downloading it but not reading contents. Change your path to read remote file to output:

```
ob_start();
$result = ftp_get($ftp_conn, "php://output", $file_list[2].'/'.date("Y/m/d").'/'.$file_lists[0], FTP_ASCII);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

or read local file:

```
ftp_get($ftp_conn, $path, $file_list[2].'/'.date("Y/m/d").'/'.$file_lists[0], FTP_ASCII);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
```